# How can I collaborate with multiple developers on a Joomla project?

Tags: mysql, database, git, joomla, versioning

My question might come as odd, but i'm trying to find a way to work on a Joomla project that will include between 15 and 20 modules and between 15 and 30 ressources (developers).

Its a student project and we cannot modify the constraints.

We are trying to find a way to handle code versioning, database versioning in the simplest possible way.

The system we thought of for now is the following :

- Use git for any code changes
- Before commit, to a dump of the database
- Commit code + database
- Push

We are aware this is not the best way and would like to know if there are any good solutions for multi-developers Joomla projects ?

Thank you in advance !

Comment: Have you looked at [Joomla Component Builder](https://github.com/vdm-io/Joomla-Component-Builder) full disclaimer I am the lead developer of JCB. JCB offers a whole new way of component development, and multi-developer integration, with powerful sharing tools. https://youtu.be/zlhFyrCGWik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When in Joomla extension development mode, you cannot and [should not use git or any versioning tool](https://www.itoctopus.com/when-to-use-svn-or-git-in-joomla-development). You should only do that once all the extensions are installed and the repository is completely, and only minor alterations to extensions are required.

The best thing that you can do is to each work on an extension separately, but on the same Joomla website. Needless to say, the risk here is if someone's extension is broken (which may bring the whole thing down) - and that's why you will need a lead developer who will interfere when this happens (and who will manage the overall quality of the work). Daily backups are a must until the system is in a stable state.

It will take you probably weeks to plan the versioning for this project, and it will not work.

Comment: Hi @itoctopus, and thanks for your answer ! 

We are going to look into re-organizing our development into multiple extensions and work separately on each of them but on separate instances of Joomla. We will then in the end bring it all together with a handful of lead devs.
We are going to keep looking into the versioning issue with a few developers though as we feel a solution for versioning CMS development would be great. 

Thanks again !